# MySQL with LIMIT does work

Tags: php, mysql, limit

I am so confused. I have this code:

```
function fetchAllArray($assoc = MYSQL_ASSOC) {
    while($rows=$this->result->fetch_array($assoc))
        $arr[]=$rows;
    return $arr;

}

function getGalleries($limit = 0,$orderby = '`created` ASC, sort_id',$ordersort = 'DESC') {

    $this->query("SELECT * FROM galleries WHERE status=1 ORDER BY ".$orderby." ".$ordersort." ".($limit==0 ? "" : " LIMIT ".$limit).";");
    $arr=$this->fetchAllArray();

    if(is_array($arr))
        return $arr;
    else
        return FALSE;
}
```

when I call it like:

```
$this->getGalleries(300);
```

this returns nothing!

When I test exact query in phpmyadmin I get results. When I remove the LIMIT from the query it works. Why is LIMIT not working here?

The code working well in localhost with LIMIT but not in server!

EDIT:
I just found that this is the 'created' string that not working on server! when I remove `created` from query, it works on server but when I include it not works! how I add this in my query!?

Comment: What's the exact query that gets executed and doesn't return expected results?

Comment: you can test the $arr length to find out whats going wrong.

Comment: MOTHER OF GOD! I just found that this is the 'created' string that not working on server! when I remove `created` in query, it works on server. how I add this in query!?

Answer (score 2):

Seems that your function doesn't get the parameter and take the default argument that is zero, so you don't get any result.

Try to put a print statement before the execution of the query to see if the query is composed well or not ...

Comment: when I printout command i get: SELECT * 
FROM galleries
WHERE STATUS =1
ORDER BY created ASC , sort_id DESC 
LIMIT 300;

Comment: Try to change the limit in this way : LIMIT 0,300

Comment: I just found that LIMIT is not the problem but the 'created' string is! when I remove it works on server. seems that mysql version of server side do not accept `created` as column name!?

Comment: Try to surround created with backticks and try again, should work

Comment: I thnk I find the problem. there is a filtering mechanism on server that filter out this string. I should change column name :|

Comment: @m3hdi: I'd rather change the server, if possible.  Looks like they're probably trying to stop [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks, but doing it in a [rather ass-backwards way](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/SQL-Injection-Protection--3.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

This is probably an error in your php code, not in the query.

Turn on the general_log to see what php actually sends

```
set global general_log = 1;
```